# Display ProgressRing when the song is preparing and hide it when the song is playing - windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I developing application windows phone 8 that play song en streaming with MediaElement.
I want display ProgressRing when the song is preparing and hide it when the song is playing. I do this code below but doesn't show ProgressRing!!

```
progressRing.IsActive = true;
mediaElement.Source = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
mediaElement.Play();
progressRing.IsActive = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to yield control to the UI thread for the progress ring to be displayed. One convenient way to do that is to await `Task.Delay` (with a long enough delay to make sure the UI can refresh):

```
private async Task Play()
{
    progressRing.IsActive = true;

    await Task.Delay(15);

    mediaElement.Source = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
    mediaElement.Play();
    progressRing.IsActive = false;
}
```

(note that you must make sure to mark your method as async)

An alternative way is to call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` (which seems counterintuitive seems you're already in the UI thread, but it works):

```
progressRing.IsActive = true;

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    mediaElement.Source = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
    mediaElement.Play();
    progressRing.IsActive = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

MediaElement.MediaOpened Event is fired when media loading has finished. 
Try adding that event to the MediaElement and move the progressRing.IsActive statement to the EventHandler method.

```
mediaElement1.MediaOpened += new   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(mediaElement1_MediaOpened);
progressRing.IsActive = true;
mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
mediaElement1.Play();


private void mediaElement1_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    progressRing.IsActive = false;
    }
```